# How to to insert a row as record type "Header" with data collection identifier as YYYY/N, count of rows and close this row as END HEADER marker

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, etl, data-modeling

Format of the report:

[image]

The report will be exported as CSV including header row on the basis of data collection identifier as "YYYY/N" (2018/4) count of rows in each file, in this case, it is "236" column F is filed upload portion that is "1" and it will be "2" for data in the file.

Comment: Do you need to insert a row, or load a file, or export a report in csv format?

Comment: i need to create a report then the end user will export it to csv but it should contain the above row so that when the file opens say e.g You have csv of "xxxx 2018/4" when you open it the format should be like this header row on top and then data follows for clients. I hope you get what i am explaining.

Comment: Can you generate a csv file directly, or does it have to be a report first?

Comment: Yes I can do that to

Comment: I ask because I wrote something to do exactly that: https://www.williamrobertson.net/documents/refcursor-to-csv.shtml

Answer (score 1):

Would `union` do any good? For example:

```
SQL> select 'HACC' a, 201 b, 'HEADER' c, extract(year from sysdate) ||'/'||count(*) d, 'END_HEADER' e
  2    from emp e
  3    where deptno = 10
  4  union all
  5  select 'HACC', 201, d.dname, to_char(e.empno), e.ename
  6    from emp e join dept d on e.deptno = d.deptno
  7    where d.deptno = 10;

A             B C              D               E
---- ---------- -------------- --------------- ----------
HACC        201 HEADER         2020/3          END_HEADER
HACC        201 ACCOUNTING     7782            CLARK
HACC        201 ACCOUNTING     7839            KING
HACC        201 ACCOUNTING     7934            MILLER

SQL>
```

Comment: this could work but how will I get the date when creating CSV?

Comment: I don't know which year (or date) exactly you want (I can't find "2018" in screenshot you posted; perhaps because it is so tiny, or 2018 doesn't exist). Anyway, if we suppose it is SYSDATE's year, then concatenate it with count. I modified code in my example; have a look, please.